# How to make geo location retrieval process faster in UWP?

Tags: c#, performance, uwp, geolocation, location

I am using Geolocator class to find current position of the device in UWP app. The location retrieval process works very fast in my compute. But when I try to run the same app in real device, then device retrieval process takes around 30 seconds.
I'm using the following code snippet:

```
var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
if (accessStatus == GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
    Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator
    {
        DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 500,
        DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High
    };

    Geoposition pos = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync()
}
```

How can I make this process faster in my devices?

Already tried by increasing the DesiredAccuracyInMeters value upto 2000 but couldn't find any improvement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High`? Try to set that to `Default`. As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation.positionaccuracy) it seems that it tries to involve many resources to get precise location => could be slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator#Methods), you can see that when you set both `DesiredAccuracy` and `DesiredAccuracyInMeters`, the one set last takes precedence:

> When neither DesiredAccuracyInMeters nor DesiredAccuracy are set, your app will use an accuracy setting of 500 meters (which corresponds to the DesiredAccuracy setting of Default). Setting DesiredAccuracy to Default or High indirectly sets DesiredAccuracyInMeters to 500 or 10 meters, respectively. When your app sets both DesiredAccuracy and DesiredAccuracyInMeters, your app will use whichever accuracy value was set last.

So you because you are setting `DesiredAccuracy` to `High`, you are effectively overriding the meters setting. To make the search faster, do not set the `High` accuracy and only set the meters value.

Comment: Thanks. I just missed the documentation part.

Answer (score 0):

I will add to Martin's question, you should use first the cached position and then use the `GetPositionAsync`, you should get a faster localization of the user in this way:

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 500;

//Check if we have a cached position
var loc = await locator.GetLastKnownLocationAsync ();
if ( loc != null )
{
    CurrentPosition = new Position (loc.Latitude, loc.Longitude);
}

if ( !locator.IsGeolocationAvailable || !locator.IsGeolocationEnabled )
{
    return;
}

//and if not we get a new one
var def = await locator.GetPositionAsync (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (10), null, true);
CurrentPosition = new Position (def.Latitude, def.Longitude);
```

Comment: I think this approach requires GeoLocator plugin, right?